# execute mysql query inside mootools element?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mootools

i am trying to execute a mysql_query after a countdown in mootools but i have no idea how to do it? so far i am able to output variabla text inside the element but i was not able to execute php code inside. anyone has a idea?

Untitled

```
 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var CountDown = new Class({

 //implements
  Implements: [Options,Events],

 //options
  options: {
    element: 'countdown',
    start: 10,
    finish: 0,
    startFont: '12px',
    finishFont: '12px',
    onComplete: $empty,
    duration: 1000
},

//initialization
initialize: function(options) {
    //set options
    this.setOptions(options);
},

//get things started
start: function() {
    this.anim();
},

//animate!
anim: function() {
    this.options.element.set('text',this.options.start--);
    var fx = new Fx.Tween(this.options.element,{
        duration: this.options.duration,
        link: 'ignore',
        onComplete: function() {
            if(this.options.start >= this.options.finish) {
                this.anim();
            } else {
                this.fireEvent('complete');
            }
        }.bind(this)
    }).start('font-size',this.options.startFont,this.options.finishFont);
}
 });





      /* usage */
      window.addEvent('domready',function() {
  var cd = new CountDown({
    element: $('countdown'),
    start: <?=$timer;?>,
    finish: 0,
    onComplete: function() {
     // here i want to execute a mysql_query instead of output these vaiablesa s text
    this.options.element.set('text','<?=$test1?><?=$test2?><?=$test3?>');

    }
 }).start();
  });
 </script>

 <div id="countdown"></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here we go again... PHP executes on the server, and generates some HTML. That HTML is sent to the client, which then loads up the Javascript and executes that on the client.

The only way to have Javascript talk to PHP is via an AJAX call. You can have PHP talk to Javascript at the time the page is generated, as you're doing with your `<?= ?>` stuff in the Javascript code. But once the page is send out to the client, AJAX is your only choice.

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on the **server**; MooTools is JavaScript running in the **browser**. You'll need to use [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to send an HTTP request to your server, instructing it to execute the PHP code which queries the database. Whatever that PHP code outputs will be sent back to the browser; you use JavaScript to parse the response and update the DOM accordingly.

MooTools gives you a nice ajax API to use called [`Request`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request), so that's probably what you'll want to learn and use. See also the [`Request.HTML` and `Request.JSON` demos](http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Request).

Comment: hi matt,that is exactly what i tried before. i am aware of the Request.HTML and request.JSON thing but i failed to implement a url call after the countdown. how can i call a url like: hello.php?variable1=hello&variable2=john AFTER the countdown? i tried to put a HTML request but i failed...but i done mind to execute a url of a file which then updates my table instead of execute the mysql_query directly...how would you do that? thank you

Comment: Well, that's the answer to your question. If you can't figure out how to use ajax, ask a new question about that.